# How to send AT commands to serial interface in Yocto Linux?

Tags: tty, serial-port, getty, yocto, minicom

I have a XBee device attached to the ttyMDF1 interface on an Intel Edison board running Yocto linux. I need to configure the XBee by sending AT commands to it.
I have tried to open a `getty /dev/ttyMDF1` but nothing happens, same using screen, also tried with `echo "+++" > /dev/ttyMDF1` and `cat /dev/ttyMDF1` with no luck eighter.

Any ideas about what I may be doing wrong or which program I could install using opkg?. Communication with the XBee should start by sending a `+++` sequence and it should reply with an *OK*

Comment: you need to set the speed `stty -F /dev/ttyMDF1 115200` or use `minicom`

Comment: for latest and greatest stuff for Intel Edison better to look here: https://github.com/edison-fw (and wiki: https://htot.github.io/meta-intel-edison/)